# How to run a ROS2 node inside docker image?

Tags: python, docker, ros2

I have a ros2 package and successfully create a docker image of it. Then when im inside the container i would like to run only one single node of the ros2 package. So first create the environment with `PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.local/bin` then  `vcs import . <system_integration/ros.repos` then `docker pull ghcr.io/test-inc/base_images:foxy`. Im running  and executing the docker with

```
docker run --name test -d --rm -v $(pwd):/home/ros2/foxy/src ghcr.io/company-inc/robot1_vnc_ros2:foxy

docker exec -it test /bin/bash
```

Then when Im inside the docker I build the package with

colcon build     --symlink-install     --event-handlers console_cohesion+     --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release     --packages-up-to system_integration

So now im inside the docker in the `root@1942eef8d977:~/ros2/foxy` and would like to run one python node. But `ros2 run package_name node_name` would not work right? Im not familiar much with docker so not sure how to run the node. Any help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can use ros2 run to run packages, you have to source the correct workspace. Otherwise you could not use auto-completion `tab` to find any packages and thus no package can be run

To do so:

1. `cd` into your the root path of your workspace
2. `colcon build` your workspace (which your packages should under the `src` directory)
3. run this line to source it `source install/setup.bash`
4. you can check it with `echo $COLCON_PATH_PREFIX` to see the path is correctly sourced
5. Try rerun the ros2 command to start your node

Answer (score 1):

Have you sourced the setup file within the container?

Where ever the package source is located, you need to run source ./install/setup.bash